# Regex and JavaScript strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working with a set of blood pressure readings, for example

```
lines[50] = '(523,112)';
```

and I am using

```
readings[i] = lines[i].slice(5,8);
```

to extract the second 3 digit number.  How can this be done with a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the desired result. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more details

```
'(523,112)'.match(/,(\d+)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
readings[i] = lines[i].match(/\d+(?=\))/);
```